# how to fetch only recent updates from a svn repository using bzr that already imported the repo

Tags: svn, repository, bazaar, bzr-svn

I once did a repository fetch from google using bzr from a svn repo like this

```
bzr svn-import http://feedparser.googlecode.com/svn/ feedparser
cd feedparser
bzr branch trunk mybranch
cd mybranch
bzr checkout
```

now the repository svn repo ( http://feedparser.googlecode.com/svn/ ) has some new updates that i want to fetch but since I changed some files in my local repo ( i.e. the bzr repo on my local machine ) how can I fetch and merge the updates with my update using bzr without loosing the update and my changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pull` command:

```
cd trunk
bzr pull http://feedparser.googlecode.com/svn/
```

or even

```
cd trunk
bzr pull
```

The latter may not work first time, but will work next time you do pull after pull with explicit URL.

After pull finished you can simply merge the changes from trunk into mybranch:

```
cd ../mybranch
bzr merge ../trunk
```

Inspect changes after merge and commit the result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `bzr update` it will merge back changes from the upstream repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a svn-import again to the imported repository, it will fetch only the new revisions.